@RolesAllowed annotation is not working in multi module gradle project
I upgraded my multi module gradle(v8.2) project from spring 5.3.34 to spring 6.1.18
In "project-core" module I have SpringWebSecurityConfigurer file -
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled=true)
public class SpringWebSecurityConfigurer{
      @Bean
      public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
            return http.build();
      }
}

I have another module "project-configuration" for which I have mentioned dependency on "project-core" module in its build.gradle file -
implementation project(":project-core")
Both these modules have RestController class with get/put/post mappings annotated with @RolesAllowed annotation.
Issue is that for "project-core" module @RolesAllowed annotation is working fine and I get Access Denied 403 with not allowed roles. But in case of "project-configuration" module, in its RestController class, the @RolesAllowed annotation is not working fine and I don't get 403.
I tried to use @PreAuthorize but same issue. I was expecting to get 403 with not allowed roles. This issue started to come in Spring Security 6, earlier in version 5 @RolesAllowed was working fine for "project-configuration" module.
